# Cumulative count if the ID in previous row matches - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is what I am trying to achieve in python. There is a simple formula in excel, what is pythonic way of handling this?

```
CUM_FREQ      ID
```

```
1          100001
2          100001
3          100001
4          100001
1          100002
2          100002
1          100003
2          100003
3          100003
4          100003
```

Everytime ID changes CUM_FREQ row should be reset to 1. 
Excel Formula IF(C3=C2,B2+1,1)

Thanks in advance!
Rahul

Comment: Can you explain what CUM_FREQ does and add an example of data input and expected output?

Comment: Updated the question.Input data is ID column, expected output is CUM_FREQ

Comment: Do you want to parse an input file or do you want to use a Pandas DataFrame or what else? Having more info would help.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to have the IDs in a list and use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to compute the counts.

```
from collections import Counter

id_list = [100001, 100001, 100001, 100001, 100002, 100002, 100003, 100003, 100003, 100003]
cum_freq = []
for i, v in enumerate(id_list):
    cum_freq.append(Counter(id_list[:i+1])[v])

print(cum_freq)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```